# brined turkey and fat

Tags: meat

I had a brined turkey that someone had cooked for the 1st time this Thanksgiving.  Typically we eat one that has been cooked in a roasting bag.  My daughter and I both noticed that the brined turkey seemed greasier. Is the total fat higher for a turkey that has been brined, compared to cooked in a roasting bag?

Answer (score 2):

Brining shouldn't have any real effect on fat content, just moisture. The issue is, that fat and water can have similar cooling feelings on the tongue, and dried fat may not feel as greasy to the hand.

I have noticed that if you take the bird straight from the brine to the pan, the skin doesn't crisp as much, leaving it feeling mushy and greasy. The best thing you can do here is after you're done brining it, dry it off thoroughly, and have it rest in the refrigerator for 3 or more hours. This will dry out the skin, and make it crispier, and the subcutaneous fat should effectively fry it.

Alternatively, you could have just gotten an unusually fatty bird. It's hard to say from just one sample.